# Dataframe column with quoted CSV to named dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am pulling some JSON formatted log data out of my SEIM and into a pandas dataframe.  I am able to easily convert the JSON into multiple columns within the dataframe, but there is a "message" field in the JSON that contains a quoted CSV, like this.

```
# dummy data
dfMyData = pd.DataFrame({"_raw": [\
            """{"timestamp":1691096387000,"message":"20230803 20:59:47,ip-123-123-123-123,mickey,321.321.321.321,111111,10673010,type,,'I am a, quoted, string, with commas,',0,,","logstream":"Blah1","loggroup":"group 1"}""",
            """{"timestamp":1691096386000,"message":"20230803 21:00:47,ip-456-456-456-456,mouse,654.654.654.654,222222,10673010,type,,'I am another quoted string',0,,","logstream":"Blah2","loggroup":"group 2"}"""
            ]})
# Column names for the _raw.message field that is generated.
MessageColumnNames =  ["Timestamp","dest_host","username","src_ip","port","number","type","who_knows","message_string","another_number","who_knows2","who_knows3"]
# Convert column to json object/dict
dfMyData['_raw'] = dfMyData['_raw'].map(json.loads)
# convert JSON into columns within the dataframe
dfMyData = pd.json_normalize(dfMyData.to_dict(orient='records'))
```

I've seen this done before with `str.split()` to split on columns and then concat it back to the original dataframe, however the `str.split` method doesn't handle quoted values within the CSV.  `pd.read_csv` can handle the quoted CSV correctly, but I can't figure out how to apply it across the dataframe and expand the output of that into new dataframe columns.

Additionally, when I split `dfMyData['_raw.message']` out into new columns, I'd also like to supply a list of column names for the data and have the new columns be created with those names.

Anyone know of an easy way to split a quoted CSV string in a dataframe column into new named columns within the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Actually all you need is to pass your data into a csv-reader, which in turn is an appropriate data type for `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
pd.DataFrame(csv.reader(dfMyData['_raw.message'], quotechar="'"), columns=columns)
```

---

**Previous answer**

We can try to convert the data into a csv and read them back with appropriate parameters:

```
import csv
from tempfile import TemporaryFile

seq = dfMyData.iloc[:,1]      # column of interest in the original data
columns = [*'ABCDEFGHIJKL']   # custom names of future data columns

with TemporaryFile() as file:

    seq.to_csv(
        file, 
        sep='\N{unit separator}',
        header=False,
        index=False,
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE
    )

    file.seek(0)    # read data from the start

    df = pd.read_csv(
        file, 
        header=None,
        names=columns,
        quotechar="\'"
    )

print(df)
```

Notes:

- `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` to avoid `\"` at the ends of each line
- `sep='\N{unit separator}'` to avoid confusion with commas
- `quotechar="\'"` when reading back because of a specific quoting inside the lines
- since we are dumping a sequence without indexes, the `'\N{unit separator}'` delimiter will never make it into the final data

Transformed data:

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you!  That one liner is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
from io import StringIO


out = pd.concat(
    [
        dfMyData,
        dfMyData.pop("_raw.message")
        .apply(lambda x: pd.read_csv(StringIO(x), header=None, quotechar="'").iloc[0])
        .add_prefix("csv_col_"),
    ],
    axis=1,
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   _raw.timestamp _raw.logstream _raw.loggroup          csv_col_0           csv_col_1 csv_col_2        csv_col_3  csv_col_4  csv_col_5 csv_col_6  csv_col_7                             csv_col_8  csv_col_9  csv_col_10  csv_col_11
0   1691096387000          Blah1       group 1  20230803 20:59:47  ip-123-123-123-123    mickey  321.321.321.321     111111   10673010      type        NaN  I am a, quoted, string, with commas,          0         NaN         NaN
1   1691096386000          Blah2       group 2  20230803 21:00:47  ip-456-456-456-456     mouse  654.654.654.654     222222   10673010      type        NaN            I am another quoted string          0         NaN         NaN
```